# Out of memory exception or Oracle Unexcepted packet read error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a asp.net Web API service end point which return a bulk data from the oracle database. I am converting the returned data in the JSON format. It was working fine, but suddenly I am getting an error saying Out of Memory exception in the string result or it is showing the Network Session: Unexpected packet read error

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
{
    using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=J;PASSWORD=C;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=T"))
    {
        var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
        var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
        DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
        var strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY where STPR_STUDY.STD_REF IN(" + srtcon + ")";
        OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand);
        DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(selectResults);
        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
        string contentDisposition = "inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json";
        //byte[] byteInfo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contentDisposition);
        //response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = byteInfo.Length;
        return response;
  }
}
```

[image]

But when I execute the same query in the Oracle DB directly it returns data. It returns over 50,000 records. The errors are inconsistent sometimes it returns the result and sometimes it returns the Out of memory exception or Oracle Unexcepted packet read error with the same filter.

Comment: That is a lot of data to slug over the network.  Not sure why it would "suddenly" occur or occasionally occur.  My guesses would be network related; when people are watching funny cat videos you will have problems.

Comment: It occurs suddenly and sometimes it just works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50,000 records sent across the network in JSON format would likely be 12 megabytes (wild guess -- probably on the low side) or more of data; and with Ethernet you have packets of roughly 1 kilobyte in size, so your response would be coming in 12MB / 1 KB per packet  ≈ 12,000 packets.

To verify size of the data, and what is causing the errors, a good approach would be to use Wireshark to capture network traffic on the machine where you are getting the errors.  It will flag network packets that are lost, display size of packets, etc.  The fact that you can invoke the query on the server without any issue points to something in the network.

Another place to look would be in the TNS listener log files on the server; that would be a quick thing to check for errors.  The command `lsnrctl status` will say where the log files are:

```
$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 28-JUL-2016 19:01:11
Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=example.com)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                27-JUL-2016 14:33:08
```

...

```
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/plsekatlasexta01/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
```

Now, solutions:

- Would you be able to break up the output into chunks that the client could request in separate requests?
- Are you selecting all columns when only some columns are needed?